# Trying to choose from a SELECT tag

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have tried the code below but it's not working.

```
driver.get("http://www.naukri.com/");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Salary']"));
Select s1 = new Select(element);
s1.selectByVisibleText("5");
```

Answer (score 0):

`element` is not a `SELECT` tag it just looks like one. You will need to click the `INPUT` element that you have in `element` and then click the `LI` that represents the desired amount, in the case listed: 5.

BTW, part of the site [Terms & Conditions](http://jobsearch.naukri.com/terms-and-conditions) are that you won't scrape the site.

> Naukri.com uses technological means to exclude Robots etc from crawling the website and scraping content. The user undertakes not to circumvent these methods.

Comment: Thanks ,@JeffC if possible could you please provide some piece of code becoz i am still not able to figure it out.